# Validation in strut2+spring framework

Tags: spring, validation, struts2

I need to do validation with Action-validation.xml

1. I have added the Ationname-validation.xml in the same path where action is residing.
2. Variable names are same as form varibles.
3. Default interceptor is added in struts.xml

But still validation is not working

Comment: have you get any kind of exception?

Comment: no i m not getting any exception.

Comment: I m not getting any exception.I am adding this part for adding one of the item.Without validation it is adding directly to DB.On sample project its working fine.

Comment: What validators are you using, and what are the actual names of `validation.xml`, their residence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use valid xml dtd type,

```
 <!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"

  "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
```

try this,if you are using Apache Struts validator.

Answer (score 0):

Its working now.
While we need to exclude any methods from validation.

```
<action name="viewInputValidator" method="viewInputValidator" class="inputValidator">
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
  <param name="validation.excludeMethods">viewInputValidator</param>
</interceptor-ref>

<result name="success" type="tiles">viewInputValidator</result>
<result name="failure" type="tiles">inputValidatorInternalException</result>
<result name="input" type="tiles">viewInputValidator</result>
</action>
```

you need to include exclude methods in the same declares action.As above mentioned code.